# USB serial number shows special character

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, usb, wmi

I have a c++ application to find the serial number of a USB device. This application works fine but for some USB devices it returns special character values like **6** and **0**

Here is my code

```
CString GetSerialNo(CString sDevId)
{
    HRESULT hres;
    CString strQuery    = "",
            strOut      = "";
    sDevId.Replace("\\","\\\\");
    //////////////////////////
    try
    {
        strQuery.Format("SELECT SerialNumber FROM win32_diskdrive where  pnpdeviceid = '%s'",sDevId);

        hres =  CoInitialize(NULL); 
        if (FAILED(hres))
        {
            return strOut;                  // Program has failed.
        }

        IWbemLocator *pLoc = NULL;

        hres = CoCreateInstance(
            CLSID_WbemLocator,             
            0, 
            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, 
            IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);

        if (FAILED(hres))
        {
            CoUninitialize();
            return strOut;                 // Program has failed.
        }

        IWbemServices *pSvc = NULL;

        hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
             _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), // Object path of WMI namespace
             NULL,                    // User name. NULL = current user
             NULL,                    // User password. NULL = current
             0,                       // Locale. NULL indicates current
             NULL,                    // Security flags.
             0,                       // Authority (for example, Kerberos)
             0,                       // Context object 
             &pSvc                    // pointer to IWbemServices proxy
             );

        if (FAILED(hres))
        {
            pLoc->Release();     
            CoUninitialize();
            return strOut;                // Program has failed.
        }

        hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
           pSvc,                        // Indicates the proxy to set
           RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // RPC_C_AUTHN_xxx
           RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // RPC_C_AUTHZ_xxx
           NULL,                        // Server principal name 
           RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_xxx 
           RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_xxx
           NULL,                        // client identity
           EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities 
        );

        if (FAILED(hres))
        {
            pSvc->Release();
            pLoc->Release();     
            CoUninitialize();
            return strOut;               // Program has failed.
        }

        IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
        hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
            bstr_t("WQL"), 
            bstr_t(strQuery),
            WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
            NULL,
            &pEnumerator);

        if (FAILED(hres))
        {
            pSvc->Release();
            pLoc->Release();
            CoUninitialize();
            return strOut;               // Program has failed.
        }


        IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = NULL;
        ULONG uReturn = 0;

        while (pEnumerator)
        {
            HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, 
                &pclsObj, &uReturn);

            if(0 == uReturn)
            {
                break;
            }

            VARIANT vtProp;

            hr = pclsObj->Get(L"SerialNumber", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
            strOut = (CString)vtProp.bstrVal;
            VariantClear(&vtProp);
            pclsObj->Release();
        }

        pSvc->Release();
        pLoc->Release();
        pEnumerator->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        if(!strOut.IsEmpty())
        {
            strOut.Trim();
        }
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        return strOut;
    }
    return strOut;  
}
```

### I'll share the output of the devices which have issue in serial Number

Caption         TOSHIBA TransMemory USB Device 
PNPDeviceID     USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_TOSHIBA&PROD_TRANSMEMORY&REV_1.00\0022CFF653F1C060D88C887E&0

### SerialNumber        0

---

Caption         Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 USB Device
PNPDeviceID     USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_KINGSTON&PROD_DATATRAVELER_2.0&REV_1.00\60A44C413BF2F0718628B8E0&0

### SerialNumber        6

If you know why the serial number is like this please share .

NOTE : The above code is working fine and the result is same in the WBEMTEST tool.

Comment: What - in your opinion - is special about character values `6` or `0`?

Comment: End of Text 
ETX6 and ETX0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a HRESULT when querying the serial number.

```
hr = pclsObj->Get(L"SerialNumber", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
```

Yet, you do not check if the operation has succeeded.  Some USB devices do not have a `SerialNumber` property.